# MVC use Authorize attributes with HttpMessageHandler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `GlobalConfigure.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute` map to a custom handler (due to dependencies, there is no way for me to implement this as a controller). But I also want for it to use the `[Authorize]` attribute.
Is there a way for me to manually call the Authorize functions? 
This attribute should only run for my custom handler.

Comment: You can manually test if the user is authenticated with `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and then route to the login page if the value is `FALSE`.

Comment: it doesnt work. At the stage the MessageHandler is run, the User is not set